# Docker not finding a path I added to File Sharing on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, caffe

I am trying to use docker to help create caffe models using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@rosstopherkeen/using-caffe-on-macos-os-x-3f923cd499e), and I am getting an error that my path is not configured, however I followed the instructions to configure the file as shown in the error below:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied:  The path /shared_folder is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker. You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.
```

I got this error running the following command:

```
docker run -ti -v /shared_folder:/root/shared_folder bvlc/caffe:cpu bash
```

I've tried adding it to my File Sharing directory directly, by editing the json file and adding / to the end of the path, but nothing has worked. I also tried putting in a directory called "private," and it gives a different error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/private/shared_folder': mkdir /private/shared_folder: operation not permitted.
```

I'm not sure where to go next and can't move forward until I am able to run this command. Any idea why Mac is not finding the path properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue by deleting "/" from in front of "shared_folder":

```
docker run -ti -v shared_folder:/root/shared_folder bvlc/caffe:cpu bash
```

Comment: Note that this is a more substantial change than it looks.  Instead of attempting to mount a `/shared_folder` directory from the host system, this uses a Docker named volume `shared_folder`, which won't be directly usable from the host.  The named volume will in fact avoid various performance and permission problems around bind mounts, and this can be the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I used the terminal. But interestingly when I run via the **terminal of Intellij IDE**, everything worked well.

I resolved the issue by adding "/" at the end of the shared_folder:
`docker run -ti -v ./shared_folder/:/root/shared_folder`